# libpcap error pcap_open_live(): BIOCSRTIMEOUT: Invalid argument

Tags: pcap, libpcap

With the following code, I get this error when I run the executable file:

```
...
dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
if(dev == NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n",errbuf);
    exit(1);
}
printf("DEV: %s\n",dev);
descr = pcap_open_live(dev,BUFSIZ,0,-1,errbuf);
if(descr == NULL)
{
    printf("pcap_open_live(): %s\n",errbuf);
    exit(1);
}
packet = pcap_next(descr,&hdr);

if(packet == NULL)
{
    printf("Didn't grab packet\n");
    exit(1);
}
...
```

And the error:

```
pcap_open_live(): gbeth0: BIOCSRTIMEOUT: Invalid argument
```

When I change

```
descr = pcap_open_live(dev,BUFSIZ,0,-1,errbuf);
```

to

```
descr = pcap_open_live(dev,BUFSIZ,0,1,errbuf);
```

sniffer does not grab anything and the program exit with this error: Didn't grab packet
and when I change 1 to 0 it does not grab anything but with errors.
What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-1 is *NOT* a valid timeout argument to `pcap_open_live()` on any platform.

0, as a timeout argument, may behave differently on different platforms, and is *not* recommended.

And `pcap_next()` is not guaranteed to wait forever for a packet to arrive; it might return NULL if the timeout expires.  If you want to capture at least one packet, try looping until `pcap_null()` doesn't return NULL.